# java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call during JDBC connection with oracle 11g

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Hi I am trying to run a `servlet` which gets the data from a simple html form and stores in oracle database and displays a message "Data Saved". I am using Eclipse Luna, Tomcat 7.0 and Oracle 11g Express Edition. When I run the the program I get this error.

> java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Got minus one from a read call
>   during JDBC connection with oracle 11g

Here is my web.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>StudentManagement</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>StudentRegServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.serv.pkg.StudentRegServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <description></description>
      <param-name>username</param-name>
      <param-value>scott</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>password</param-name>
      <param-value>tiger</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>StudentRegServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/stdreg</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>CourseRegServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.serv.pkg.CourseRegServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
  <param-name>username</param-name>
  <param-value>test</param-value>
   </init-param>

   <init-param>
   <param-name>password</param-name>
   <param-value>test</param-value>
   </init-param>

  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CourseRegServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/coursereg</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>driver</param-name>
  <param-value>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
  <param-name>url</param-name>
  <param-value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8080:XE</param-value>
  </context-param>
</web-app>
```

My Servlet

```java
package com.serv.pkg;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.GenericServlet;
import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class CourseRegServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/CourseRegServlet")
public class CourseRegServlet extends GenericServlet {
    private Connection conn; 
    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config)throws ServletException
    {
        System.out.println("Executing init method from coursereg.html");
    ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext( );
    String driver=sc.getInitParameter("driver");
    String url=sc.getInitParameter("url");
    String username=config.getInitParameter("username");
    String password=config.getInitParameter("password");

    try {
        Class.forName(driver);
        System.out.println("driver loaded");
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password );
    } catch ( Exception e) {
        System.out.println("catching from init" +e);
    }

    }


    public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        System.out.println("Executing service method from coursereg.html");
          int cid = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cid"));
          String c_name = request.getParameter("c_name");
          int fee = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("fee"));

          try {
              System.out.println("exe1");
            PreparedStatement stmt=conn.prepareStatement("insert into course values(?,?,?)");
            System.out.println("exe2");
            stmt.setInt(1, cid);
            stmt.setString(2, c_name);
            stmt.setInt(3, fee);
            int i = stmt.executeUpdate();
            if(i!=0){
                System.out.println("course registered");
            }else
            {
                System.out.println("registration failed");
            }
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
          out.println("Data saved");
    }

    public void destroy(){
        try {
            System.out.println("Executing destroy method from coursereg.html");
            conn.close();
        } catch ( Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is your *listener* really on port 8080 - not the more standard 1521? Your URL seems to be pointing to the web management page, not the database itself? Trying to connect to an HTTP port could give this kind of error.

Comment: In that case could you suggest me how my code should be? coz Changing my port number from 8080 to 1521 gives me this error java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Answer (score 1):

The default port for the database listener is 1521, not 8080 (which is the default HTTP port, from XML DB); so your URL should be:

```
  <param-value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE</param-value>
```

If your listener is on a non-standard port then use that instead. Also the `:XE` part means it'll try to connect with the SID XE. You might prefer to use the service name, which is hopefully also XE, which would be denoted by a slash instead of a colon:

```
  <param-value>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE</param-value>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Changing my port number from 8080 to 1521 gives me this error **java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied**

Comment: @SaddamHussain - your web.xml sets the username and password twice; to scott/tiger for StudentRegServlet which looks reasonable, but then to test/test for CourseRegServlet, which probably does not. Check which values it's actually using to connect; and whether you can log with those credentials through SQL\*Plus. I'd have thought just changing the test/test entries would cure this though. Do you really want/need those to be set at servlet level though?

Comment: Actually I am trying to workout on the context object example. in this exercise I have two tables 1. Student and 2.Course I use the context object to load the drivers and through studentreg.html form values I am trying to update Student table and from coursereg.html form values I am trying to update course table. Since both the code does the same job and no change in code but little bit so I didn't posted the whole code.

Comment: @SaddamHussain - that's fine, but shouldn't the username and password be set at context level, if the two servlets are accessing tables in the same schema? This is a side issue though; the credentials need to be correct first, wherever they are set.

Comment: Ok now I removed my second Servlet file code from the web.xml file .Now I only have one table one servlet but still getting the same error.

Comment: I think the problem is with URL

Comment: The ORA-01017 error message is telling you the problem is with the username/password, not the URL. It's one of Oracle's clearer errors. Unless you're connecting to entirely the wrong database which isn't likely here. I can't see what you've removed or what values you still have. Have you tried debugging - print out the username/password before you use them and see what you are getting? Or connecting to Oracle directly with the same credentials?

Comment: Thank you It works. I was entered the wrong port number 8080 and also the user name and password as you have mentioned in your first reply. Could you clear my doubts on this ? actually when I installed Oracle express edition , a shortcut was created on my desktop , when i double clicked that it opens in a browser with the following link  [link](http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/f?p=4950:1:1060645659655821) so I thought my port number is 8080 ... What is this 8080 here?? if its not my port number?

Comment: @SaddamHussain - they are both right, but for different services. 8080 is an HTTP port you can access through your browser. 1521 is the SQL\*Net listener which is used to connect to the database directly, using a different protocol. [Read more in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/network.htm#ADMQS156).